# Ho to apply the same formula to groups

Tags: r, grouping

My dataset, `unitatsconsum_2021` is such:

```
structure(list(NUMERO = structure(c(21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 
24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 27, 28), format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    unitats_consum = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.9, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 
    2.5, 2.5, 2.2, 1, 1, 2), edat = c(17, 51, 17, 14, 44, 36, 
    3, 67, 63, 35, 48, 17, 13, 73, 67, 73), membresllar = c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L
    )), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -16L), groups = structure(list(NUMERO = structure(c(21, 
22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28), format.stata = "%12.0g"), .rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2:4, 5:7, 8:9, 10:13, 14L, 15L, 16L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I want to calculate a new variable, `unitats_consum`, which should be  equal to: 1 + 0.5*((observations if edat>13)-1) + 0.3*(observations if edat>=13).

The result of this equation should be the same for each identical `NUMERO`, which is the identifier. So far I have tried the following:

```
Unitatsconsum_2021 <- Unitatsconsum_2021 %>%
  group_by(NUMERO) %>%
  mutate(unitats_consum = (1 + 
                             0.5 * (ifelse(edat > 13, membresllar - 1, 0)) +
                             0.3 * (ifelse(edat <= 13, membresllar, 0))))
```

The desired output is:

[image]

So, in the code, `membres_llar` should count the number of observations where `edat` > 13 and where `edat` >=13, in each case respectively.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't seem to match the description. How could the value be the same for all observations for the same NUMERO when the values of edat is changing? What's the formula for making them the same?

Comment: How do you get 1.8 with NUMERO is 23?

Comment: In `NUMERO` 23, there are two observations where `edat` > 13 and one <=13. So, the formula is: 1+ 0.5*((observations if edat>13)-1) + 0.3*(observations if edat>=13), so in this case: (1 + 0.5*(2-1)+ 0.3*1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not match your output for two rows, but I believe it is what you are looking for:

```
Unitatsconsum_2021 <- Unitatsconsum_2021 %>%
  group_by(NUMERO) %>%
  mutate(
    unitats_consum = 1 + 0.5 * (sum(edat > 13) - 1) + 0.3 * sum(edat <= 13)
  )

Unitatsconsum_2021
# # A tibble: 16 × 4
# # Groups:   NUMERO [8]
#     NUMERO  unitats_consum  edat  membresllar
#     <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl> <int>
# 1   21      1               17    3
# 2   22      2               51    3
# 3   22      2               17    3
# 4   22      2               14    3
# 5   23      1.8             44    3
# 6   23      1.8             36    3
# 7   23      1.8             3     3
# 8   24      1.5             67    2
# 9   24      1.5             63    2
# 10  25      2.3             35    4
# 11  25      2.3             48    4
# 12  25      2.3             17    4
# 13  25      2.3             13    4
# 14  26      1               73    1
# 15  27      1               67    1
# 16  28      1               73    3
```

For NUMERO 21, we should have 1, since 1 + 0.5 * (1 - 1) = 1 and the same for NUMERO 28.